# Can't find my installed application

Tags: android

Greets,

Made some app on android. I for the life of me can't get it to install on the phone as a stand alone application. It runs fine when I deploy from eclipse but never remains on the device. any idea whats happening?

I put the apk file on a web server, went to the address downloaded and installed but still it wasn't to be found.

I'm lost!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure your application manifest defines an activtity with a category of LAUNCHER. For example:

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Otherwise, the Android apps screen won't pick it up.

Comment: Was missing <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"